# CamelCase Does Not Work with JMS and FosRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle

Here is the code:

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: false
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener: true
    #disable_csrf_role: ROLE_USER
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
    view:
        view_response_listener: force

nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: false
        allow_origin: []
        allow_headers: []
        allow_methods: []
        expose_headers: []
        max_age: 0
    paths:
        '^/api/':
            allow_origin: ['*']
            allow_headers: ['*']
            allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
            max_age: 3600

sensio_framework_extra:
    request: { converters: true }
    view:    { annotations: false }
    router:  { annotations: true }
```

**Property.php**

```
/**
 * Property
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="property")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"house" = "House", "office" = "Office"})
 */
abstract class Property
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=true)
     */
    private $price;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    function setPrice($price) {
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}
```

**House.php**

```
/**
 * House
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="house")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class House extends Property
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numberOfRooms", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $numberOfRooms;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numberOfBathrooms", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $numberOfBathrooms;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hasGarage", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $hasGarage;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hasYard", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $hasYard;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hasGas", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $hasGas;

    function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    function getNumberOfRooms() {
        return $this->numberOfRooms;
    }

    function getNumberOfBathrooms() {
        return $this->numberOfBathrooms;
    }

    function getHasGarage() {
        return $this->hasGarage;
    }

    function getHasYard() {
        return $this->hasYard;
    }

    function getHasGas() {
        return $this->hasGas;
    }

    function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    function setNumberOfRooms($numberOfRooms) {
        $this->numberOfRooms = $numberOfRooms;
    }

    function setNumberOfBathrooms($numberOfBathrooms) {
        $this->numberOfBathrooms = $numberOfBathrooms;
    }

    function setHasGarage($hasGarage) {
        $this->hasGarage = $hasGarage;
    }

    function setHasYard($hasYard) {
        $this->hasYard = $hasYard;
    }

    function setHasGas($hasGas) {
        $this->hasGas = $hasGas;
    }
}
```

**PropertyType.php**

```
class PropertyType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('price')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Cboujon\PropertyBundle\Entity\Property'
        ));
    }
}
```

**HouseType.php**

```
class HouseType extends PropertyType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
            ->add('numberOfRooms')
            ->add('numberOfBathrooms')
            ->add('hasGarage')
            ->add('hasYard')
            ->add('hasGas')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Cboujon\PropertyBundle\Entity\House'
        ));
    }
}
```

When I request `http://localhost:8000/api/houses/4` I get a response with status code 500 and the following content:

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Property Cboujon\\PropertyBundle\\Entity\\House::$numberofrooms does not exist","class":"ReflectionException","trace": ...
```

If I rename the attribute from `$numberOfRooms` to `$numberofrooms` the application returns a new error

```
{"error":{"code":500,"message":"Internal Server Error","exception":[{"message":"Property Cboujon\\PropertyBundle\\Entity\\House::$numberofbathrooms does not exist","class":"ReflectionException","trace": ...
```

I guess the problem is the camelcase so I tried configure

```
fos_rest:
    body_listener:
        array_normalizer: fos_rest.normalizer.camel_keys
```

But I keep getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried do the request `[POST] http://localhost:8000/api/houses/` with a JSON parameter and I get the same error but the data is inserted in the database. I'm really confused.

Comment: You may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'll just add a note here about `camel_keys`. A quote from a blog post: `The camel_keys array normalizer will recursively transform all properties containing underscores to their camel case equivalent before the request is populated with the body data.`

Comment: Are you using config files to control your serializations? If so, can you post one up? It looks like you have a property "numberofrooms" in your file put the property is actually "numberOfRooms" so it is causing the error although I could be wrong as all the information isn't really available.

Comment: @Qoop I haven't a config file to control the serialization. Just the annotation. House entity was created from the database with the attributes numberofrooms and `numberofbathrooms` but then I changed it to `numberOfRooms` and `numberOfBathrooms` and I updated the schema.